# cordova-plugin-contacts crashes the app

Tags: android, cordova, contacts, cordova-plugins

I encounter an aleatory crash with my Cordova Application on android smartphone One plus One (device product:bacon model:A0001 device:A0001).

I didn't find any issues mgt on the repository : https://github.com/alsorokin/cordova-plugin-contacts

Is there any error on my code ? Can you tell me what I could do ?
Thank you.

Here is the AngularJS function :

```
getAllContacts : function(){
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  var onSuccess = function(contacts) {
    deferred.resolve(contacts);
  };
  var onError = function(contactError) {
    deferred.reject(contactError);
  };

  var options = new ContactFindOptions();
  options.filter = "";
  options.multiple = true;
  var fields = ["*"];

  navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);


  return deferred.promise;
},
```

Here is the crash LOG I got from ADB LOGCAT:

```
I/chromium(10453): [INFO:CONSOLE(95)] "getContacts", source: file:///android_asset/www/app/components/contacts/ContactsService.js (95)

D/LBSSystemMonitorService(  758): handleMessage what - 4

D/Wiper_jni(  758): Send Network Location.

I/chromium(10453): [INFO:CONSOLE(22)] "$ionicView.enter ListContactsCtrl", source: file:///android_asset/www/app/components/contacts/importContactsController.js (22)

I/chromium(10453): [INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "homeCtrl", source: file:///android_asset/www/app/components/home/homeController.js (5)

W/CursorWindow(17276): Window is full: requested allocation 168 bytes, free space 75 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes

I/art     (  758): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 186688(8MB) AllocSpace objects, 9(144KB) LOS objects, 28% free, 40MB/56MB, paused
4.019ms total 193.548ms

D/HeadsetStateMachine( 3762): Disconnected process message: 10, size: 0

W/ActivityManager(  758): getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10086 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output

I/art     (17276): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 36472(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 19MB/33MB, paused
2.271ms total 58.172ms

W/ActivityManager(  758): getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10103 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output

D/HeadsetStateMachine( 3762): Disconnected process message: 10, size: 0

E/CursorWindow(10453): Could not create CursorWindow from Parcel due to error -12.

--------- beginning of crash

E/AndroidRuntime(10453): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-3

E/AndroidRuntime(10453): Process: net.myapp.app, PID: 10453

E/AndroidRuntime(10453): android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window could not be created from binder.

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:137)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:42)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:685)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:683)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor.readFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:75)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:34)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:30)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:424)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:478)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactAccessorSdk5.photoQuery(ContactAccessorSdk5.java:910)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactAccessorSdk5.populateContactArray(ContactAccessorSdk5.java:439)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactAccessorSdk5.search(ContactAccessorSdk5.java:271)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager$1.run(ContactManager.java:93)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)

E/AndroidRuntime(10453):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

W/DropBoxManagerService(  758): Dropping: data_app_crash (1587 > 0 bytes)

D/LogFetchServiceManager( 4073): Received entry added

W/ActivityManager(  758):   Force finishing activity 1 net.myapp.app/.MainActivity

D/OpenGLRenderer(  758): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
```